# Обработка полей формы в Yii

Tags: forms, post, php, yii

Сервер получает от клиента POST-массив с данными из формы добавления объекта (недвижимость). В форме помимо прочих полей имеется список тэгов для объекта в виде чекбоксов, текстовых полей и выпадающих списков, который я генерирую вручную (через цикл). При добавлении объекта используется модель для тэгов, в единственно поле 'name' которой заносятся значения из списка тэгов. В экшне '**create**' контроллера '*ObjectController*' происходит сохранение тэгов из формы в поля модели:

```
$model->attributes = $model->normalizeTags($_POST['ObjectTags'])
```

Так как мне нужно, чтобы в базу сохранялись только отмеченные тэги, я фильтрую '*$_POST['ObjectTags']*' при помощи функции '**normalizeTags**', отсеивая поля с пустыми значениями. В результате эта функция возвращает массив, аналогичный тому, что пришёл от клиента, просто без пустых полей. Однако, когда я сохраняю новый массив в модель, вылетает предупреждение со следующим сообщением:

htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

и трейс указывает мне на текстовое поле из списка тэгов. Я в замешательстве, так как значение, получаемое из текстового поля заносится в новый массив как строка, и никак не может быть массивом. Проблема именнно в текстовом поле, ибо если я заменяю его на чекбокс, то сохранение проходит нормально. В чём может быть ошибка?

Заранее благодарен за конструктивные ответы.

**UPD**: код, генерирующий список тэгов:

```
for($c = 0; $c < count($tags); $c++) {
    echo CHtml::label($tags[$c], 'name');
    if($tags[$c] == 'balcony area')
        echo $form->textField($model, 'name', array('name'=>'ObjectTags[name][balcony_area][]')).' m^2';
    else
        echo $form->checkBox($model, 'name', array('name'=>'ObjectTags[name][]','value'=>$tags[$c]));
}
```

Comment: Сложно о чем-то говорить не видя html, который генерируется для формы. Приведи пример html-а где есть 2-3 чекбокса.

Comment: @KITE, обновил вопрос. Кажется, я понял в чём загвоздка. Только сейчас обратил внимание, что при использовании textField массив POST возвращает значение этого поля как массив. Но почему?..

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему.

Получаю от клиента POST-массив с атрибутами, пропускаю его через следующую функцию:

```
public function normalizeTags($tags) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
        if($value !== '0') {
            if ($key === 'balcony_area')
                $output[] = array('name'=>"balcony area: $value m^2");
            else if ($key === 'kitchen_area')
                $output[] = array('name'=>"kitchen area: $value m^2");
            else
                $output[] = array('name'=>$key);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

и в теле экшна циклом обхожу каждый элемент сгенерированного этой функцией массива:

```
$filteredTags = $tags->normalizeTags($_POST['ObjectTags']);
foreach ($filteredTags as $tag) {
    $tags->attributes = $tag;
    $tags->save();
}
```

Вывод: нельзя запихивать в поле attributes массив с повторяющимися ключами. Например, если поле в БД - 'name', то в POST-массиве не должно быть больше одного ключа 'name'.